# Can't use any network_mode value on task definition whilst target group target type = 'alb'

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

This is my target group:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "hello-world-nginx-target-group" {
  name = "hello-world-nginx"
  target_type = "alb"
  port = 80
  protocol = "TCP"
  vpc_id = "vpc-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxb"
}
```

This is my service:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "hello-world-nginx-service" {
  name = "hello-world-nginx"
  cluster = "ste-test"
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.hello-world-nginx-task-definition.arn
  desired_count = 1
  launch_type = "EC2"

  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type = "binpack"
    field = "cpu"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.hello-world-nginx-target-group.arn
    container_name = "hello-world-nginx"
    container_port = 80
  }

  placement_constraints {
    type = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [eu-west-2a]"
  }
}
```

This is my task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "hello-world-nginx-task-definition" {
  family = "service"
  network_mode = "bridge"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name = "hello-world-nginx"
      image = "hello-world-nginx:latest"
      cpu = 10
      memory = 512
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort = 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

  volume {
    name = "service-storage"
    host_path = "/ecs/service-storage"
  }

  placement_constraints {
    type = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [eu-west-2a]"
  }
}
```

For the task definition `network_mode` value I have tried (for testing) `host` , `bridge` and `awsvpc` and all of them return the following error:

`The provided target group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xxxxxxx:targetgroup/hello-world-nginx/xxxxxxxxx has target type alb, which is incompatible with the bridge (or host or awsvpc) network mode specified in the task definition.`

Comment: You are using the wrong `target_type` value. For EC2 instances it should be `target_type = "instance"`.

Answer (score 1):

Target type should be `"ip"` or `"instance"` on your target group and protocol `http`, because you are using ALB, not NLB

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "hello-world-nginx-target-group" {
  name = "hello-world-nginx"
  target_type = "instance"
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = "vpc-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxb"
}
```